# Коллтрекинг MANGO-OFFICE как сделать, чтобы номер подменялся в нескольких местах на сайте?

Tags: javascript, html

На сайте есть несколько `<span>` в которых должен отображаться подменяемый номер, но при вставке кода колтрекинга подменяется только верхний, нижний подменяется на номер по умолчанию.
Код колтрекинга:

```js
(function(w, d, u, i, o, s, p) {
        if (d.getElementById(i)) { return; } w['MangoObject'] = o; 
        w[o] = w[o] || function() { (w[o].q = w[o].q || []).push(arguments) }; w[o].u = u; w[o].t = 1 * new Date();
        s = d.createElement('script'); s.async = 1; s.id = i; s.src = u;
        p = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; p.parentNode.insertBefore(s, p);
    }(window, document, '//widgets.mango-office.ru/widgets/mango.js', 'mango-js', 'mgo'));
    mgo({calltracking: {id: 600, elements: [{selector: '#mango-calltracking'}]}});
```

```html
<span id="mango-calltracking">номер1</span>
<span id="mango-calltracking">номер2</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем верно написан код, нужно так

```
<script>

(function(w, d, u, i, o, s, p) {
    if (d.getElementById(i)) {
        return;
    }
    w['MangoObject'] = o;
    w[o] = w[o] || function() {
        (w[o].q = w[o].q || []).push(arguments)
    };
    w[o].u = u;
    w[o].t = 1 * new Date();
    s = d.createElement('script');
    s.async = 1;
    s.id = i;
    s.src = u;
    p = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    p.parentNode.insertBefore(s, p);
}(window, document, '//widgets.mango-office.ru/widgets/mango.js', 'mango-js', 'mgo'));
mgo({
    calltracking: {
        id: id Вашего виджета,
        elements: [{
            selector: '#mango-calltracking-1'},
              {selector: '#mango-calltracking-2'
        }]
    }
});

</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Для подмены нескольких номеров на сайте необходимо изменить код колтрекинга и html-верстку следующим образом:

1. Для каждого `<span>` c необходимо задать собственный id, например:

```html
<span id="mango-calltracking-1">номер1</span>
<span id="mango-calltracking-2">номер2</span>
```

2. После этого необходимо в функцию mgo в скрипте добавить соотвутствующие селекторы для каждого id, следующим образом:

```js
(function(w, d, u, i, o, s, p) {
    if (d.getElementById(i)) {
        return;
    }
    w['MangoObject'] = o;
    w[o] = w[o] || function() {
        (w[o].q = w[o].q || []).push(arguments)
    };
    w[o].u = u;
    w[o].t = 1 * new Date();
    s = d.createElement('script');
    s.async = 1;
    s.id = i;
    s.src = u;
    p = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    p.parentNode.insertBefore(s, p);
}(window, document, '//widgets.mango-office.ru/widgets/mango.js', 'mango-js', 'mgo'));
mgo({
    calltracking: {
        id: 600,
        elements: [{
            selector: '#mango-calltracking-1'},
           {selector: '#mango-calltracking-2'
        }]
    }
});
```

**Внимание!** Скрипт на сайт необходимо вставить после всех `<span>`, иначе номера подменяться не будут.